# Query with HAVING COUNT> clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get ids of clients who have more than one document with expiration date 2220-01-01. What am I doing wrong?
Error: near line 32: near "(": syntax error

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM DOCUMENTS GROUP BY CLIENT_ID HAVING COUNT(DOCUMENT_NUMBER) >1 (
SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE VALID_TO = '2220-01-01';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the `WHERE` clause in the main query and there is no need of a subquery:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID 
FROM DOCUMENTS
WHERE VALID_TO = '2220-01-01' 
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I guess that in a table named `DOCUMENTS` the column `DOCUMENT_NUMBER` should be unique, but if there is a case of duplicates then use `DISTNCT`:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DOCUMENT_NUMBER) > 1
```

Comment: could you also help me figure out if this is the right syntax
`
SELECT CLIENT.NAME FROM CLIENT, DOCUMENTS WHERE CLIENT.ID = DOCUMENTS.CLIENT_ID AND DOCUMENTS.DOCUMENT_NUMBER IS NULL;
`

Comment: Syntactically it is correct, if the table and column names are correct, but I would write it with proper join syntax: `SELECT CLIENT.NAME FROM CLIENT INNER JOIN DOCUMENTS ON CLIENT.ID = DOCUMENTS.CLIENT_ID WHERE DOCUMENTS.DOCUMENT_NUMBER IS NULL`

Comment: i'm getting nothing tho... maybe this is not the correct way to show which clients don't have documents assigned to them? like in my table  if a client doesn't have a doc number it's not written as null, there is simply no data of them in Documents table

Comment: @Ifwehadamonkey I can't say why you don't get any data. Post a question with sample data indicative of your actual data and expected results to clarify your requirement.